# Creating a Control-M job to stop/start services on a unix server

Tags: shell, unix, control-m

I have a .sh script for stopping a service on a unix server, and I need to create a control-m job to schedule this and automate it to run daily. How do I use control-m to call this script? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can call scripts in various ways, either as a command or by specifying the script or even as an embedded script -

1. Command - create a Control-M job as an "OS" job (in version 8 or 9) and in the "what" drop-down select "command". Fill in the command field with the full command as if you were running the job from a command prompt;

/pkgs/prod1/scripts/myscript.sh

the advantage of this is you can add parameters and they will be seen;

/pkgs/prod1/scripts/myscript.sh -restart

2. Script - as with the previous option but from the "what" drop-down select "script" and enter the full path and then the script name. Obviously you can't use parameters with this method.
3. The embedded script option will add the script code to the Control-M gui, which is a handy way to centralise things.